# Ansible gets localhost USER wrong?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to setup a register i.e check if file exists before executing a task in ansible

```
- name: check CRAN R script exists
  stat:
    path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/scripts/R/cran.R"
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: cran

  tags: r_extras
```

This task is part of the playbook as runs as sudo

```
- name: installing common apt dependencies, pip python packages as well as java
  hosts: base
  remote_user: "{{ sudo_guy }}"
  roles:
            # need to have non previlidged installer guy
            - make_sw_guy
            # apt-get installation
            - common

  become: true
```

when I run playbook like this

```
ansible-playbook -vvvv -i my_hosts all.yml --tags r_extras
```

I get this error

```
fatal: [bio_training -> localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_name": "stat"
    }, 
    "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", 
    "module_stdout": "", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"
}
```

Because Ansible thinks I'm `root` .. which seems a bit silly to me, but I might be missing the point?

How to check that local file exists? AND/OR how to get `$USER` variable of the localhost

---

I can "fix" this problem by adding `become_user: $USER` but I don't know how to make this generic..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`become` directive set for the role is valid for all tasks, including those with `delegate_to`.

Effectively, you attempt to run the task locally with `sudo` command in front and have a requirement for providing the password set in `/etc/sudoers`.

There's nothing silly in what Ansible does here and it does not "think" you are `root`, actually if it "thought" you were root, it wouldn't ask for the password.

You can add `become: false` to the task.

Comment: thanks, I think I still don't fully get - forget that when you use `become` in ansible it'll run everything wih sudo prefix.. its just a little unintuitive for local_actions, because you specify `sudo` for the remote..

Comment: I can't see any `local_action` task in your question. You used the phrase in the above comment first.

Comment: I believe `delegate_to: localhost` and `local_action` are the same thing.. Are they not?

Comment: I don't know, but I can imagine there are differences especially in the connection details local vs. SSH, or existing vs new. Maybe it's a topic for a new question if you were interested.

Answer (score 0):

As @techraf points out, `become: false` does the trick. In my case, I needed to add my own public key to the user on the remote machine. This enables me to log in with public key authentication. I was struggling a bit since there are so many variables that define a user (username, ansible_user, ansible_user_id etc.). And those variables tend to change depending on becoming root and whether the task is executed remotely or locally.

I decided to check the facts that are generated by default at the start of each playbook run. This means that they are set before I become root and before I log into the remote host. You can get the username with `lookup('env','USER')`. Similarly, I used the variable that defines my own home folder to solve the problem below:

```
- name: Add ssh key from local machine
  become: false
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ ansible_user }}" # Remote user
    key: "{{ lookup('file', lookup('env','HOME') + '/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```